# product placement on shelf with sql

Tags: sql-server, data-analysis, sql-server-2019

I have two tables

I have the first table of product entry:

```
Declare @ProductTb AS Table(
                            ProductId Int IDENTITY(1,1), 
                            Amount Int --The amount of product inventory
                            )
Insert Into @ProductTb
    Values
        (1600),
        (2000),
        (3200),
        (3000),
        (3100),
        (1300),
        (1600),
        (3000),
        (500),
        (300),
        (6000),
        (5000),
        (1500),
        (1100)
```

The second table is the shelves that have the number of rows per shelf and the capacity of each shelf specified in it:

```
Declare @ShelfTb As Table(
                            ShelfId Int IDENTITY(1,1), --The unique number of each shelf
                            Capacity Int,  --The capacity of each row of the shelf
                            NumberOfShelf TinyInt -- The number of rows per shelf
                            )

Insert Into @ShelfTb
    Values
        (9500,12),
        (8500,8),
        (10000,15)
```

The third table is also a temporary table that is supposed to make the list of the second table:

```
Declare @ShelfList As Table(
                            Id Int IDENTITY(1,1),
                            ShelfId Int, --The unique number of each shelf
                            Capacity Int,  --The amount of capacity of this row
                            RowNumber Int --The row number of the shelf
                            )
;
With Cte1
AS
(
    Select
            s.[ShelfId],
            s.[Capacity],
            1 RowNumber
        From @ShelfTb As s
    Union All
    Select
            c.[ShelfId],
            c.[Capacity],
            c.[RowNumber] + 1
        From Cte1 As c
        Inner Join @ShelfTb As s On s.[ShelfId] = c.[ShelfId]
        Where   c.[RowNumber] < s.[NumberOfShelf]

)
Insert Into @ShelfList
Select *
    From Cte1 As c
```

I want to arrange the entry of these products on the shelves so that if the capacity of the row is full, start from the next row. My effort, which is a beginner in sql, is the code below, and in the following, whatever effort and search I did, I did not get the result:

```
Select
        *,
        Sum(p.[Amount]) Over (Partition By s.[ShelfId], s.[RowNumber] Order By s.[ShelfId], s.[RowNumber], p.[ProductId]) SumAmount

    From @ShelfList As s, @ProductTb As p
    Order By s.[Id], s.[ShelfId], s.[RowNumber]
```

Thank you for the effort you make to help me

Comment: Don't use `,` to join tables. Use `JOIN` instead, which will the tell you that you're missing the join condition.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: @jarlh Looks like you have a fully reproducible example there...

Comment: Is the size of each product the same? And the size of each shelf space the same? Assuming those are true you are looking for a running total. If those are not true then this is the classic bin packing problem which is extremely difficult to solve.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about your expected results? What do you actually want to get?